# Why doesn't my cart collection increment as expected?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create a button where if the user clicks the "add to cart" button on the site, the counter at the button for "items in cart:" goes up. Right now it is not doing that. I am new to Vue therefore any help would be appreciated :)

Here is my app.components.js file

```
const Library = Vue.component('Library', {
    // this function is run AFTER the props have been passed in
    data() {
        // without chaining
        // let libraryCollection = new LibraryCollection();
        // libraryCollection.addItem(new Book('Interaction Design', 200));
        // libraryCollection.addItem(new Movie('Paw Patrol!', 78));
        // libraryCollection.addItem(new Movie('Harriet', 122));
        // libraryCollection.addItem(new Book('Brown Bear, Brown Bear', 0));

        return {
            //library: libraryCollection
            library: new LibraryCollection()
                .addItem(new Book('Interaction Design', 200))
                .addItem(new Movie('Paw Patrol!', 78))
                .addItem(new Movie('Harriet', 122))
                .addItem(new Book('Brown Bear, Brown Bear', 0))
        }
    },

    template: `
      <div class="card-columns">
        <library-item v-for="item in library" :item="item"></library-item>
        <div class="card">
          <p>Checked out: {{library.checkedOutItems().length}}</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    `
})

const LibraryItemComponent = Vue.component('LibraryItem', {
    // values/bindings passed to this component
    props: {
        item: Object
    },

    computed: {
      typeOfItem(){
          return this.item.constructor.name;
      }
    },

    // the view
    template: `
            <div class="card" :class="item.isAvailable() ? 'border-success' : 'border-warning'" style="border-width: 3px;">
<!--                <h3 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h3>-->
<!--                <p class="card-text" v-if="item.constructor.name == 'Book'">Pages: {{item.pages}}</p>-->
<!--                <p class="card-text" v-if="item.runningTime">Running Time: {{item.runningTime}}</p>-->
            <div class="card-body">
              <component :is="typeOfItem" :item="item"></component>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <button @click="item.checkOut()" class="btn btn-secondary">Check Out</button>
              <button @click="item.checkIn()" class="btn btn-secondary">Check In</button>
              <button @click="EventBus.$emit('addItem', item)" class="btn btn-secondary">Add to Cart</button>
              <button @click="item.favorite()" class="btn btn-secondary">{{item.isFavorite ? 'Unfavorite' : 'Favorite'}}</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        `,
});

const BookComponent = Vue.component('Book', {
    props: {
        item: Book
    },

    template: `
            <div class="book">
                <h3 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h3>
                <p class="card-text">Pages: {{item.pages}}</p>
            </div>
        `,
});

const MovieComponent = Vue.component('Movie', {
    props: {
        item: Movie
    },

    template: `
            <div class="movie">
                <h3 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h3>
                <p class="card-text">Running Time: {{item.runningTime}}</p>
            </div>
        `,
});

const Cart = Vue.component('Cart', {
    // this function is run AFTER the props have been passed in
    data() {
        // without chaining
        // let libraryCollection = new LibraryCollection();
        // libraryCollection.addItem(new Book('Interaction Design', 200));
        // libraryCollection.addItem(new Movie('Paw Patrol!', 78));
        // libraryCollection.addItem(new Movie('Harriet', 122));
        // libraryCollection.addItem(new Book('Brown Bear, Brown Bear', 0));

        return {
            //library: libraryCollection
            cart: new CartCollection()
        }
    },

    template: `
      <div class="card-columns">
        <cart-item v-for="item in cart" :item="item"></cart-item>
        <div class="card">
          <p>Items in cart: {{cart.length}}</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    `
})
```

This is my app.models.js file

```
function LibraryCollection(){
    this.__proto__ = []; // as of ES6 (2015)

    this.addItem = function(item){
        this.push(new LibraryItem(item));

        // allows us to chain methods
        return this;
    }

    this.checkedOutItems = function(){
        return this.filter(function(item){
            return !item.isAvailable();
        })
    }
}
// current and pre-ES6
LibraryCollection.prototype = [];
LibraryCollection.prototype.constructor = LibraryCollection;

// let divs = $('div');
// divs.hide().show().html('asdf');
function LibraryItem(media){
    // list of possible values (enum)
    const STATUSES = {CHECKED_OUT: 'out', CHECKED_IN: 'in', LOST: 'lost'}

    // decorating/adding functionality to an existing object
    media.status = STATUSES.CHECKED_IN;
    media.isFavorite = false;

    // methods
    media.checkIn = function(){
        this.status = STATUSES.CHECKED_IN;
    }

    media.checkOut = function(){
        this.status = STATUSES.CHECKED_OUT;
    }

    media.isAvailable = function(){
        return this.status === STATUSES.CHECKED_IN;
    }

    media.favorite = function() {
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
        return this.favorite;
    }

    return media;
}
function CartCollection(){
    this.__proto__ = []; // as of ES6 (2015)

    this.addItem = function(item){
        this.push(item);
        console.log(this);

        // allows us to chain methods
        return this;
    }
    this.removeItem = function(libraryItem){
        let index = this.indexOf(libraryItem);
        this.splice(index,1);
    }
}
// current and pre-ES6
CartCollection.prototype = [];
CartCollection.prototype.constructor = CartCollection;
```

Comment: Can you show the code that handles the `addItem` event?

Comment: @tony19 
its in the LibraryItem

Comment: `LibraryItem` emits the event, but nothing listens to it.